# How to repeat an action each X seconds in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

I want the action "randomNumber" to happen once every 30 seconds.

```
public class INScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    int rnd;

    void Start()
    {
         Invoke("randomNumber", 30);   
    }

    public void randomNumber()
    {
        rnd = Random.Range(0, 100);
        Debug.Log(rnd);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [InvokeRepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) to achieve it. In your case it would look something like this:

```cs
void Start()
{
     InvokeRepeating("randomNumber", 0, 30);   
}
```

Where 0 is the initial delay before the method is called (So, instant) and 30 is every 30 seconds that method will be repeated

Comment: thanks that's what i was exactly looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `Coroutines`.

```
bool running;

IEnumerator DoWork(int time) 
{
    // Set the function as running
    running = true;
    
    // Do the job until running is set to false
    while (running)
    {
        // Do your code
        randomNumber();
        
        // wait for seconds
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    }
}
```

To call it use the following:

```
// Start the function on a 30 second time delay
StartCoroutine(DoWork(30));
```